# Как достать числовые значения из строки?

Tags: c#

Имеется строка MoreValue|Value10|Product40. Мне нужно получить две переменные.
Например:
int value = 10;
int id = 40;
Помогите пожалуйста заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например так

```cs
string input = "MoreValue|Value10|Product40";
string[] tokens = input.Split('|');

List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
foreach(string token in tokens)
{
    if (int.TryParse(string.Concat(token.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c))), out int number))
        numbers.Add(number);
}

int value = numbers[0]; // 10
int id = numbers[1]; // 40
```

Или еще можно с помощью регулярного выражения

```cs
string input = "MoreValue|Value10|Product40";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+");
int value = int.Parse(matches[0].Value); // 10
int id = int.Parse(matches[1].Value); // 40
```

Comment: Докапываться до ошибок самого кода не буду, так как, видимо он написан напрямую в ответ без проверки, но на выходе получается 0, 40, так что отрабатывает неверно

Comment: @SoulOFTrue Вроде дает [верный результат](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BBKVxF), не? Единственное да, тут `input.Split('|')` даст массив, а приводится к `string`, ну и `if` условие не имеет закрывающей скобки, но это мелочи реализации, который в силах понять и исправить любой человек.

Comment: Так я это всё исправил и получил 0, 40 в студии

Comment: @SoulOFTrue Ну я вам выше дал ссылку на онлайн компилятор, который собрал данный код и запустил его, выдав на экран результат, как видите, там все сходится. Так что, смотрите что вы там не так у себя делаете.

Comment: Тот же самый код, только foreach прошелся по листу, нулевой элемент = 0. А вот 1 = 10, а 2 = 40. Может я чего-то недопонимаю? https://dotnetfiddle.net/cgO31y

Comment: @SoulOFTrue Не смущает желтый восклицательный знак, который вам на `));` намекает?

Comment: Ух, пора мне по ходу менять описание в профиле)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ написано прямо в редакторе SO, все верно. Исправил ошибки, спасибо большое.

Comment: @aepot, способ с регулярными выражениями это то что я и искал. Спасибо вам большое.

Answer (score 3):

В один проход без выделения дополнительной памяти:

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> input = "MoreValue|Value10|Product40";

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(input[i]))
    {
        int j;
        for (j = i + 1; j < input.Length && char.IsDigit(input[j]); j++)
        {
        }

        int number = int.Parse(input[i..j]);                                        
        Console.WriteLine(number); // помещаем в коллекцию и т. п.

        i = j;
    }
}
```